# How to install Google Chrome on Kali Linux 2016 (Kali GNU/Linux Rolling \n \l)

Tags: kali-linux, chrome

I've been trying to install Google Chrome on to my Kali Linux OS, but to no avail.

This is my process:

```
root@localhost:~/Downloads# dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 303734 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (55.0.2883.87-1) over (55.0.2883.87-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-8) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

When I try to install **libappindicator1**, I get:

```
root@localhost:~/Downloads# apt-get install libappindicator1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libappindicator1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libappindicator1' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install Chrome successfully

Comment: I get the following output with that:  
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package libappindicator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`libappindicator1`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/libappindicator#) package is available for kali-linux rolling.

Edit your `sources.list` as follow:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

then run:

```
ap-get update
apt-get install libappindicator1
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
apt-get -f install
```